# How to make GTK work under Cygwin?

Tags: c++, gtk, cygwin

I'm trying to make Gtk works under Cygwin/Code Blocks, but I encountered this error:

> cannot find -lgtk-win32-3.0

The file gtk-win32-3.0.lib is located at

> C:\gtk\lib

But when I try to add this file in the linker setting (Build option -> Linker settings -> Link Libraries), it does nothing.

Any idea ?

(It perfectly work with minGW)

Thanks

EDIT: I eliminated all remains of my old gtk's installation (the one downloaded on the official site made for minGW) and I also replaced the PATH variable by the good one.

Here is my path viariable: C:\cygwin64\bin

After that I had some file missing error when I compiled, so I added all correct paths into my search directory, but I don't think it was the good method, because now I have something like 10 path into my search directory ...

Anyway, now I have, again, the same problem than before:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-win32-3.0

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Make up your mind. Either you want to use Gtk for Windows, in which case forget linkage through Cygwin, or you want to have a Cygwin-running application using Gtk - in which case you need to run "setup.exe" and install Gtk package with all its dependencies (that is, X server and X libraries etc.).

Comment: I first tried to install Gtk package throught the Cygwin installer, but it was like nothing was installed, (File gtk\gtk.h missing, then after adding the correct path into search directory another file was missing ..., and at the end it never worked)

Comment: I then followed a tutorial on internet showing how to make it work with the gtk bundle downloaded on the official site, but I have the problem I explained before.

If there is a way to make the cygwin's gtk package work (a tutorial or something) I woul'd gladly use it ...

Comment: If you need header files, you have to install packages with names ended with "-devel" (or "-dev" on Debian - I'm not sure which of these is used by Cygwin). If you install "libgtk2" then you'll get only the "runtime" package which contains dynamic libraries. To compile something from sources and link against gtk, you need something like libgtk2-devel

Answer (score 1):

gtk on cygwin is not different from gtk on other Unix-like systems.

Assuming you are looking of GTK3, install the
  **libgtk3-devel**
package so that you have the needed headers and libraries.